# Rewrite a property name in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a library that has a configuration class with `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix ="b")` and `@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "b", name= "c")`, in the project where I included this configuration class, the property "b" is nested under a property called "a" instead of being at the root level of the properties.yml, with this the property "b" name is "a.b" and the configuration class will get ignored, the property name needs to be kept "a.b" in the property file, is there a way to tell spring boot to ignore the "a" prefix for the property "b" or to rewrite the property name from "a.b" to "b" after application.yml gets loaded ?

Comment: Do you not have control over the class with `@ConfigurationProperties` and `@ConditionalOnProperty`?

Comment: Yes exactly the configuration class is in a third party library, and in my current project, the properties shall be organized in a specific way where the "b" should be under the property "a", I could exclude the configuration class in the library and create it again with @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "a.b") But wanted to know is there a feature in spring to rewrite a property name

Comment: `@ConditionalOnProperty` requires a `name`, not just a prefix. It can't match a prefix, it has to be told a specific property to match. Did you leave something out when you adapted the code for this question?

Comment: yes, true I have missed name property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (probably, depending on the exact context of the config class you're working with) use YAML anchor and alias to meet this need. YAML anchors are similar to anchors (`<a>` tags) in HTML; you mark some part of the yaml with an anchor, then refer to it with a reference somewhere else. The reference is an *alias* to the anchored value.

In your example, assuming the conditional config class is something like this:

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "b", name = "foo")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix ="b")
@Getter @Setter
public class SO_75435896 {

    private String foo;
}
```

You can have a YAML config like this to populate it:

```yaml
a.b: &b-alias
  foo: bar

b: *b-alias
```

The anchor name (`b-alias` in my example) can be whatever you want, there's nothing special about that name I chose.

---

If you want to read more about YAML anchors, [this is a decent explanation](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/yaml-anchors/). It's part of Bitbucket documentation, but provides a pretty good general-purpose explanation with examples. There are, of course, plenty of other web pages about YAML anchors.

Answer (score 0):

So your configuration class and properties files cannot be adapted. You can rename it at runtime in your `application.yml` :

### BProperties

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix ="b")
public class BProperties {
    private String c;
    private String d;
}
```

And this properties file :

### my-props-file.properties

```
a.b.c=value1
a.b.d=value2
```

You can rename the properties at runtime in your `application.yml` (define in classpath under src/main/ressources/) :

### application.yml

```yaml
b:
  c: ${a.b.c}
  d: ${a.b.d}
```